# FPDF error Missing or incorrect image file

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using this code to take an image as input and print it on a pdf
using FPDF but I am getting error while adding any image format like jpeg,jpg,png,gif.

Error:

> Warning: getimagesize(arc.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\CV Builder\assets\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1202
>   FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: arc.jpg

My code is

```
$pdf->Image($_POST['pic'],10,10,-300);
```

Comment: What $_POST['pic'] is suppose to have?

Comment: You need a full file path, not just the image name... `getimagesize(arc.jpg)` vs `getimagesize(/full/server/path/to/arc.jpg)`

Comment: I want to pass the path from a user input using form

<input id="exampleFormControlInput0" type="file" name="pic">